# Создание мобильного приложения с фреймом сайта

Tags: app, ios, android

Есть желание создать 2 приложения для android и iphone, но нет времени на разработку да и вообще сил. Сначала смотрел на Phonegap, но сейчас присмотрелся снова и понял что все это мне не нужно. Сайт новостной+блоги, то есть плюшки в виде файловых api и акселометров мне вообще не нужны.
По роду деятельности я фронтенд разработчик и знаю css3+html5+js как свои 5 пальцев. Умею писать легкие, но сложные красивые сайты. То есть анимация и прочее будет не на js, а transitions (css3) итд. Насчет интерфейса - не проблема, сделаю определение платформы и версии, после чего буду рисовать нужный интерфейс с подгрузкой только нужного (оптимизация везде).
Меня интересует - что я потеряю, ибо не учел?

Comment: Уже не раз обсуждали на этом форуме, поищите по тэгам iOS и Android. [Например эта тема][1]


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/231690/android-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B

Answer (score 1):

Потеряете пользователей iPhone4 и возможно 4s, ибо на этих девайсах анимации будут дико лагать.
Xодят слухи, что производительность вебкита в UIWebView специально урезана.